# Hibernate with Maven and Java 11 gives org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, java-11

I am struggling building a simple Hibernate with or without JPA, Maven and Java 11 project. This is a javafX project and shouldn't hinder using Hibernate.

I couldn't find any project example with the latest versions and I could not use older version because it would give the same error.

Here is the dependency tree of my pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {

                Configuration config = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
                config.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
                serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(config.getProperties());
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
                sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            }

            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zuseDB?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer customer = new Customer(
                "BPG", "Zubeir", "Mohamed", "mail", "112"
        );

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(customer);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        HibernateUtil.shutdown();

        // launch();
    }
```

Model class

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;
    public String companyName;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public String phone;
    @CreationTimestamp
    public Timestamp createdAt;

    public Customer(String companyName, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phone) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Customer() {}
...etc.
```

The error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.htwsaar.zuse/com.htwsaar.zuse.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:27)
    at com.htwsaar.zuse/com.htwsaar.zuse.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at com.htwsaar.zuse/com.htwsaar.zuse.IndexApplication.<clinit>(IndexApplication.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
    at com.htwsaar.zuse/com.htwsaar.zuse.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:21)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public long com.htwsaar.zuse.model.Customer.id accessible: module com.htwsaar.zuse does not "exports com.htwsaar.zuse.model" to module org.hibernate.orm.core
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.ensureAccessibility(ReflectHelper.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findField(ReflectHelper.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessFieldImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessFieldImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.3.Final/org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is the module-info. Make sure to open and export the right package to org.hibernate.orm.core inside the module info and export it

`opens com.htwsaar.zuse.model to org.hibernate.orm.core; exports com.htwsaar.zuse.model;`

That should work.